# How do I get a single element from a linq query using Take

Tags: c#, linq

In C#, if you use Take(1) and the list has no elements, you get an exception. For instance, I have this snippet:

```
from secRegister in db.Reports.SecRegisters().Where(sr => sr.IssuerID == -1).Take(1);
```

I put in a phony IssuerID of -1 to ensure that there are no elements returned. How can I get the first element only, while also checking to make sure the list has at least one element?

Comment: Can you use [IQueryable.DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.defaultifempty?view=net-8.0)?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand you, but you can probably use `FirstOrDefault()` - it will return the first matching element if there is any.

Comment: `you get an exception` no you don't, you get an empty enumerable. Using `FirstOrDefault` is better though. What was the actual exception and what was the actual code that threw?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return just the first element from and IEnumerable or IQueryable, throwing an exception if there is no such element, use First:

```
from secRegister in db.Reports.SecRegisters().Where(sr => sr.IssuerID == -1).First()
```

If you want to return just the first element from and IEnumerable or IQueryable, returning default(T) if there is no such element, use FirstOrDefault:

```
from secRegister in db.Reports.SecRegisters().Where(sr => sr.IssuerID == -1).FirstOrDefault()
```